# How to enable "Simplified View for Web Pages" setting programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility

I need to enable "Simplified View for Web Pages" setting in Accessibility settings. Is there any way I can do this?

[image: Simplified View for Web Pages]

Comment: Isn't that a **user** option?  So you want to force a setting on the user?

Comment: Yes. I want to open the link in reader mode in chrome.